# ReportLab integration into QGIS returns error message "no module named reportlab"

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, reportlab

I want to use ReportLab in my own plugin which I have written for QGIS. I have installed ReportLab for the python versions 2.4, 2.5 and 2.6. The package is respectively installed  into the site-packages folder (e.g. C:/Python24/Lib/site-packages/reportLab).

If I want to use the tool in my plugin, the plugin returns the error "ImportError: no module named reportLab". I have set the path to the modul into the environment variables, but this doesn´t help.

I try to import the module by "from reportLab.pdfgen import *".

Do you have any other suggestions or ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want Qgis to use the python lib, you have to put it in

C:\Programs\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages

(or whereever your Qgis is installed to). The C:\Python24 installation will not be used by Qgis.

Comment: That works! Thx!