# No module named Tkinter

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, installation, windows-10, tkinter

I'm working with a QGIS plugin developed with Python. This plugin is running normally in QGIS 2.6 in a Windows XP, however when I try to instail this same plugin on QGIS 2.18 in a Windows 10, this error appears: "No module named Tkinter".

I already searched about and all the possibilities that I found of error and the way to fixed isn't applyed to my problem.

Does this error happen because of the windows version, the QGIS version or another problem?

Comment: Possibly same issue as in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31141/reportlab-integration-into-qgis-returns-error-message-no-module-named-reportlab?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

This may be a `path` problem.

Consider trying this, check if the location of the module you want to import is in the PYTHONPATH and, if not, then set the PYTHONPATH as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Even Through this question is old I would like to share my experience with this Problem:

I am using mathplotlib for displaying graphics in a plugin. Some of my co-workers got the same error as described by OP.

The solution was to insert the imports into the function which actually need mathplotlib. SO insteadt of importing it in the head of your file create a function along the lines of:

```
def load_mpl(self):
   # import here the needed functions from mpl
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib import colors as mplcol
```

Use this function to add the functionality as needed.